# Omitting the first line from any Linux command output

Tags: linux

I have a requirement where i'd like to omit the 1st line from the output of `ls -latr "some path"` Since I need to remove `total 136` from the below output

[image]

So I wrote `ls -latr /home/kjatin1/DT_901_linux//autoInclude/system | tail -q` which excluded the 1st line, but when the folder is empty it does not omit it. Please tell me how to omit 1st line in any linux command output

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Pipe it to `awk`:

```bash
    awk '{if(NR>1)print}'
```

or `sed`

```bash
    sed -n '1!p'
```

Comment: also `sed '1d'`

Answer (score 410):

The `tail` program can do this:

```
ls -lart | tail -n +2
```

The `-n +2` means “start passing through on the second line of output”.

Comment: Note that some `tail` implementations require the `-n` flag for that, as in `tail -n +2`

Comment: You could also use `find . -name . -o -ls -prune`, but that produces somewhat different output.

Comment: @Mat: So it seems, though it worked without when I tried (on OSX).

Comment: it used to work with `coreutils` tail, but it's been deprecated, then removed. You now get `tail: cannot open '+2' for reading: No such file or directory` (coreutils 8.7). Sad thing is other implementations don't accept `-n`...

Comment: @Mat: Some need it, others won't take it? Ugh! Ugh ugh ugh ugh! That's disgusting.

Comment: Yep, it's sad. Though you're mostly ok using `-n` on modern systems. Solaris (<=10?) might still be an issue.

Answer (score 33):

```bash
    ls -lart | tail -n +2 #argument means starting with line 2
```

Answer (score 25):

This is a quick hacky way: `ls -lart | grep -v ^total`.

Basically, remove any lines that start with "total", which in `ls` output should only be the first line.

A more general way (for anything):

`ls -lart | sed "1 d"`

`sed "1 d"` means only print everything but first line.

Comment: Using `grep` to filter for this task is dangerous in general; it could match things unexpectedly.

Comment: Sometimes yes, and I think it's not the best solution... but that ls command always leads entries with the directory permissions. It's not ideal as grep continues to check each line, and ls behaves differently with other flags.

Comment: this is just semantics, but technically it means delete the first line from the stream.

Comment: better hope you don't have i file with total in its name that you want to know about

Answer (score 5):

You can use `awk` command:

For command output use pipe: `| awk 'NR>1'`

For output of file: `awk 'NR>1' file.csv`