# how to make grep ignore first line and process other line

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I need to remove line beginning with '#' in some txt file. but ignoring the first line as it header. how to make grep ignore first lines and remove any line beginning with # for rest of the lines?

```
cat sample.txt
#"EVENT",VERSION, NAME
1,2,xyz
1,2,abc
1,2,asd
1,2,ert
#"EVENT",VERSION, NAME
1,2,xyz
1,2,abc
1,2,xyz

cat sample.txt | grep -v "^\s*[#\;]\|^\s*$" > "out.txt"
```

but this removes the header too!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Omitting the first line from any Linux command output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7318497/608639), [Print a file skipping first X lines in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/604864/608639), etc.

Comment: i dont think its same. I need to write header in the output file too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '2,${/^#/d}' sample.txt
```

From second row (`2`) to last row (`$`): search (`/.../`) for rows beginning (`^`) with `#` and delete (`d`) them. Default action of sed is to print current row.

Output:

```
#"EVENT",VERSION, NAME
1,2,xyz
1,2,abc
1,2,asd
1,2,ert
1,2,xyz
1,2,abc
1,2,xyz
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1b;/^#/d' file
```

Ignore the first line and delete any other lines that start with `#`.

Answer (score 2):

Applying an arbitrary command to all but the first line - a "header" - of a file or stream of tabular data is such a common task for me that I define a helper utility called `body` for it:

As a shell function (put this in your `~/.bashrc` or equivalent):

```bash
body() {
  IFS= read -r header
  printf '%s\n' "$header"
  "$@"
}
```

Now:

```
$ cat sample.txt | body grep -v '^#'
#"EVENT",VERSION, NAME
1,2,xyz
1,2,abc
1,2,asd
1,2,ert
1,2,xyz
1,2,abc
1,2,xyz
```

Credit: adapted from: [Command line tools for doing data science](https://github.com/jeroenjanssens/dsutils/blob/master/body), where it's a one of many handy data tools you can put in your shell's PATH variable. Wish many of these could be canonicalized as standard UNIX tools.

Comment: Perfect for grepping `lsof` and `ps` results and keeping the header!

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! I completely agree that this should be in the canon.

Answer (score 1):

Try a combination of `head` and `grep` like so:

```
head -1 sample.txt > out.txt && grep -v "^#" sample.txt >> out.txt
```

**Result**

```
#"EVENT",VERSION, NAME
1,2,xyz
1,2,abc
1,2,asd
1,2,ert
1,2,xyz
1,2,abc
1,2,xyz
```

**Alternate method**

```
grep "^#" sample.txt | head -1 > out.txt && grep -v "^#" sample.txt >> out.txt
```

That is - grep lines beginning with # but just choose the first one and write it to a file. Then, grep all lines not starting with # and append those liens to the same output file.

Comment: When the header line doesn't start with `#`, it goes wrong. Also wrong is `head -1 sample.txt out.txt && grep -v "^#" sample.txt >> out.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

This will cause any awk to print each line if its line number is 1 or it doesn't start with `#`:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || !/^#/' file
#"EVENT",VERSION, NAME
1,2,xyz
1,2,abc
1,2,asd
1,2,ert
1,2,xyz
1,2,abc
1,2,xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu sed

```
sed '0,/^#/n;/^#/d' sample.txt
```